# Embed img inside svg marker not displaying

Tags: javascript, svg

I am embedding image inside svg tag and set as marker url, image not displaying it is showing as broken even though image is valid. How can i display image? In following fiddle i tried to show svg marker. svg marker not displaying image which is already embedded in svg tag.

```
 <div id="map_canvas"></div>
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map(
 document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var time = "00:15:30";
var testIcon = {
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
  url: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf-8,<svg width="100" height="100" 
  class="crop-shapes"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> <line x1="28" y1="40" 
  x2="32" y2="60" style="stroke:#666; stroke-width:1"/><line x1="32" 
  y1="60" x2="50" y2="50" style="stroke:#666; stroke-width:1"/><circle 
  cx="45" cy="30" r="20" fill="#2ECC71" style="stroke:#000; stroke-
  width:1"/><text id="timer_text" class="timer" x="30" y="32" 
  fill="#000000" font-size="9" font-weight="bold">00:10:30</text>
  <circle id="svg_circle" cx="20" cy="70" r="15" fill="#ffffff" 
  style="stroke:#000; stroke-width:1"/><image 
   xlink:href="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.png" x="0" 
   y="45" height="50px" width="50px"/></svg>'

   }
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: map.getCenter(),
   map: map,
   icon: testIcon,
   title: 'Hello World!'
   });

   }
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k5cv8a8d/6/

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that show what you tried so far? And please embed your code directly in your answer. Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 1):

You've two issues

1. The # character is [reserved as the start of a fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) so even the non-image parts of your marker URL are invalid. Any # characters should be replaced by %23
2. An image cannot have external references so you'll need to [base64 encode the inner png image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) so the image would become

   ```
   <image xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...etc" />
   ```